# Browsermob dependecy insertion cannot work with allure testng

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, allure, browsermob

I'm trying to change requests headers using browsermob, but I can't even insert the dependency. I don't know if there are any incompatibilities between allure and browsermob, I already tried to downgrade the allure version and really I have no clue about what is happening.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
   <artifactId>browsermob-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.5</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Just inserting this dependency and running my basic test I get the below error messages:

> [ERROR] org.testng.ITestNGListener: Provider
>   io.qameta.allure.testng.AllureTestNg could not be instantiated [INFO] 
>   [INFO] Results: [INFO]  [INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0,
>   Skipped: 0 [INFO]  [ERROR] There are test failures.
>
> Please refer to /mypath/my-project/target/surefire-reports for the
>   individual test results. Please refer to dump files (if any exist)
>   [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream. There was an
>   error in the forked processorg.testng.ITestNGListener: Provider
>   io.qameta.allure.testng.AllureTestNg could not be instantiated
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There
>   was an error in the forked processorg.testng.ITestNGListener: Provider
>   io.qameta.allure.testng.AllureTestNg could not be instantiated    at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:675)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:285)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:248)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1217)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1063)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:889)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)    at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

Here is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <source>11</source>
               <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
               <argLine>-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"</argLine>
               <systemPropertyVariables>
                  <java.awt.headless>true</java.awt.headless>
               </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
               <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                  <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                  <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
               </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
   <dependencies>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
         <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
         <version>3.141.59</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <scope>compile</scope>
         <version>4.13-rc-2</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
         <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
         <version>2.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
         <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
         <scope>compile</scope>
         <version>7.1.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/releases/tag/2.13.2 -->
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
         <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
         <scope>test</scope>
         <version>2.13.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
         <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
         <version>2.8.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>allure-java-commons</artifactId>
         <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
         <scope>compile</scope>
         <version>2.13.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
         <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
         <version>2.13.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
         <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
         <version>2.13.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl -->
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
         <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
         <scope>test</scope>
         <version>2.13.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi -->
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>jansi</artifactId>
         <groupId>org.fusesource.jansi</groupId>
         <version>1.18</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
         <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
         <version>3.8.1</version>
         <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.lightbody.bmp/browsermob-proxy -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
         <artifactId>browsermob-core</artifactId>
         <version>2.1.5</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <groupId>org.example</groupId>
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <properties>
      <aspectj.version>1.9.5</aspectj.version>
      <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>
   <reporting>
      <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <reportVersion>2.10.0</reportVersion>
            </configuration>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </reporting>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you find an answer to your issue?
I just had the same problem, and after hours of research, I fixed it by just reordering dependencies in pom.xml file: your dependencies to allure MUST be below your dependencies to browserMobProxy in the file... for a reason I can't explain.

So I think this would work for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <source>11</source>
               <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
               <argLine>-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"</argLine>
               <systemPropertyVariables>
                  <java.awt.headless>true</java.awt.headless>
               </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
               <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                  <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                  <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
               </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
   <dependencies>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
         <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
         <version>3.141.59</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <scope>compile</scope>
         <version>4.13-rc-2</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
         <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
         <version>2.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
         <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
         <scope>compile</scope>
         <version>7.1.0</version>
      </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.lightbody.bmp/browsermob-proxy -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
         <artifactId>browsermob-core</artifactId>
         <version>2.1.5</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/releases/tag/2.13.2 -->
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
         <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
         <scope>test</scope>
         <version>2.13.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
         <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
         <version>2.8.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>allure-java-commons</artifactId>
         <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
         <scope>compile</scope>
         <version>2.13.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
         <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
         <version>2.13.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
         <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
         <version>2.13.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl -->
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
         <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
         <scope>test</scope>
         <version>2.13.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi -->
      <dependency>
         <artifactId>jansi</artifactId>
         <groupId>org.fusesource.jansi</groupId>
         <version>1.18</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
         <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
         <version>3.8.1</version>
         <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <groupId>org.example</groupId>
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <properties>
      <aspectj.version>1.9.5</aspectj.version>
      <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>
   <reporting>
      <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <reportVersion>2.10.0</reportVersion>
            </configuration>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </reporting>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```